# /usr/lib/apt/methods/http eating my bandwidth!

Tags: apt

I've noticed (using nethogs), that `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` has multiple processes, which consume ALL of my bandwidth. I want to disable the process(es).

I've tried everything: `trickle`, `killall`, etc., but nothing has worked.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When and for how long?

Answer (score 7):

It is because, in Ubuntu `16.04` when there are security updates available for it, it automatically downloads and install them without notifying the user.

To disable this functionality you can visit `Software & Update` and under `Update` tab, change `when there are security updates` to `Display immediately`.

[image]

Comment: didnt work, I think it is some kind of service using that app

Answer (score 3):

`apt` does have (or at least, did have) configurable options for this. Run this from a terminal.

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download
```

And paste in the following:

```
Acquire
{
    Queue-mode "access";
    http
    {
        Dl-Limit "50";
    };
};
```

That will limit apt-get (over HTTP) to 50KB/s but just change the `Dl-Limit` value to whatever suits your circumstances best. Save the file and you're done.

Comment: This is not a solution, nor does this file exist in 16.04 distribution.  This only limits the speed.  I want to shut it down until *I* do apt update.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the software updates are downloaded in the background, you can disable this feature in the settings of the Update Manager.

Comment: no you cannot.  I tried this and set everything to do not install/download/check never.  Nope.. it still does 3mb

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill the process simply run the following command:

```
sudo kill PID
```

Replace PID with the process ID that you can find in nethogs or top.
But as you know this process is for updating Ubuntu and killing it will not upgrade your system and you should manually run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` later on.

Comment: Kill an `apt` process, and suffer the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Looks like you can set metered connections:

[image]

My bandwidth (15GB / month) was getting killed by this as well. Major usage, like 2-3 GB per day. It costs me $35USD per 5GB.

I had nothing else to lose, and was unable to determine which process was attempting to use those files. various attempts at using `netstat -tup`, `nethogs`, `iptraf`, `lsof`, etc.

#### hacky solution for stopping apt from downloading updates in the background

```sh
####
# could break stuff, not sure of the side effects. 
# However, it killed the process using up all my bandwidth
####
sudo mv /usr/lib/apt/methods/https /usr/lib/apt/methods/old.https
sudo mv /usr/lib/apt/methods/http /usr/lib/apt/methods/old.http
```

- ubuntu 18.04

What I found was that the `_apt` user was the culprit, haven't found a solution to make it stop. So, still have the files renamed.

- [What is the sandbox user '_apt' on my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810202/what-is-the-sandbox-user-apt-on-my-system)

**side effects**

- `sudo apt-get install` will fail to work, just `mv` the files back

Comment: That is really EVIL!! Especially I checked `metered connection` in wifi settings.

Comment: @yurenchen ah thanks for pointing that out, found this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711949/set-wifi-as-metered-connection/), I didn't know it was slated for development when i wrote this answer ( 18.04 ). do you know offhand if it exists in the current LTS? just checked ... oh, nice! looks like it exists in 22+

Comment: I have to say， with `metered connection`  be checked on ubuntu22， it still eat bandwidths. so I say it's EVIL. and user can't disable `security updates` easily.

Answer (score 0):

To find the culprit, get the `PID` of the `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` (pick one), then use `pstree` with `-s` (show parent processes) and `-p` (show PIDs):

```
$ pstree -sp 4976
systemd(1)───apt.systemd.dai(4920)───apt.systemd.dai(4926)───apt-get(4958)───http(4976)
```

Then use `ps` to get the details of parent processes:

```
$ ps 4958 4926 4920
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4920 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
 4926 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held update
 4958 ?        S      0:00 apt-get -qq -y update
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution for this problem: *this solution work fine for me*

### The solution:

- Open terminal
- Copy This Command `cd /usr/lib/apt/methods` and paste it into terminal and hit enter
- Then copy this command `sudo mv https https_renamed` paste it into terminal and hit enter

**And BOOM The Program not runing any more**

### What we just did:

we renamed the file 'https' so it can't run, i don't know what is the consequences. but i got no problems.

Answer (score 0):

meet the same situation (on ubuntu 22.04),
and try to find out who's behind the scenes.

## 1️⃣ trys

### ➊ cron-apt unattended-upgrades

// check packages about automatic installation

```
$ apt list cron-apt unattended-upgrades

unattended-upgrades/jammy,jammy,now 2.8ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
```

// stop & disable

```
sudo systemctl stop unattended-upgrades.service
sudo systemctl disable unattended-upgrades.service
```

I'll observe for a while and give feedback

ref:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=337534

### ➋ apt-daily apt-daily-upgrade

// check services

```
systemctl status apt-daily apt-daily-upgrade
systemctl status apt-daily.timer apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

I have not try this yet.
I'll disable it if ➊ not work

### ➌ packagekit

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/usr-lib-apt-methods-https-bandwidth-usage-4175659678/#post6033308

I have encountered this process

### Ⓧ other thing

if disable auto update check,
maybe you need manually check update.

```
$ update-manager
```

## 2️⃣ dig

After some tries I'm a little tired,
I want to find out who's behind the scenes.

I repalce `/lib/apt/methods/http` with my script, to log the caller.

and I only found this (on ubuntu 22)

### 1. packagekitd

```
2023-08-17T23:23:33: ------- /usr/lib/apt/methods/https 
systemd,1 splash
  └─packagekitd,85361
      └─https,158496 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
          ├─https,158497 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
          │   └─pstree,158500 -alc -hps -UC age 158496
          └─tee,158498 -a /run/test/apt_https.out
```

I think it's `packagekit`.

so I stop it when I use mobile network.

```sh
systemctl stop packagekit
systemctl status packagekit
```

### 2. update-manager

when I run `update-manager`, I also got

```
2023-08-18T01:10:22: ------- /usr/lib/apt/methods/https 
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,2166 --user
      └─update-manager,184012 /usr/bin/update-manager --no-update --no-focus-on-map
          └─https,184791 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
              ├─https,184792 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
              │   └─pstree,184795 -alc -hps -UC age 184791
              └─tee,184793 -a /run/test/apt_https.out
```

### 3. apt

when I run `apt update` or `apt install`, I got

```
2023-08-19T01:27:29: ------- /usr/lib/apt/methods/http 
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,2166 --user
      └─python3,3405 /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
          └─bash,3426
              └─sudo,186528 apt update
                  └─sudo,186529 apt update
                      └─apt,186530 update
                          └─http,186532 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
                              ├─http,186533 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
                              │   └─pstree,186536 -alc -hps -UC age 186532
                              └─tee,186534 -a /run/test/apt_https.out
```

### 4. aptd

I don't remember what trigger this

```
2023-08-19T01:11:07: ------- /usr/lib/apt/methods/https 
systemd,1 splash
  └─aptd,184875 /usr/sbin/aptd
      └─https,184886 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
          ├─https,184887 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
          │   └─pstree,184890 -alc -hps -UC age 184886
          └─tee,184888 -a /run/test/apt_https.out
```