# Set Wifi As Metered Connection

Tags: wireless, 15.10

I'm running on Ubuntu 15.10(KDE). I have enabled automatic updates on many applications.I'm now connected to Wifi Hotspot from my phone so don't want Ubuntu to auto update apps and save my bandwidth to reduce usage as much as possible.In windows there is an option to set a Wifi as metered connection and windows wouldn't auto update the applications similarly how to do it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet. It is drafted [in the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates), to not check for updates when a connection is detected as a **mobile broadband** connection.

For now, you should **disable** auto-updates or check for updates, if you use your mobile connection too often, to save bandwitdh, then re-enable it when you connect to wifi.

Answer (score 11):

From Ubuntu **20.04** They added metered connection option.

**GUI:**

Open `Wi-Fi setting` click on the `⚙ Gear Icon` **next to** `your wifi SSID`. **At the bottom** there is a `Metered Connection` checkbox.

**Terminal:**

Turn on:

```
nmcli connection modify YOUR_WIFI_SSID connection.metered yes
```

Show current status:

```
nmcli -f connection.metered connection show YOUR_WIFI_SSID
```

Comment: But there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1881712) that can make gnome-software think your connection is metered even when you've set it as unmetered.

Answer (score 1):

##### Command-line Interface

1. Get the device's current connection

   ```
   nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CONNECTION --mode tabular device show $DEVICE | head -n1
   ```

   `-t` is required as there is a space appended at the end
2. Show current metered status

   ```
   nmcli -f connection.metered connection show $CONNECTION
   ```

   Where `$CONNECTION` is the string returned by the previous command.
3. Change metered status

   The valid statuses are `yes`, `no`, and `unknown`. `unknown` is the default, which will do the guessing based on things like the DHCP option 
   eg:- `ANDROID_METERED`
4. Now disable the metered connection:

   ```
   nmcli connection modify $CONNECTION connection.metered no
   ```

   Change `$CONNECTION` by the output of the first command.

##### Graphical User Interface

1. Go to settings (by searching settings in the application launcher and then opening the settings app)
2. There navigate to the Wi-Fi settings:

> [image]

3. There go to the current connection settings
4. You will see a screen like this:

> [image]

5. As you can see my connection isn't metered, but your checkbox may be ticked, so, just untick it and click on `Apply`.