# What is the sandbox user '_apt' on my system

Tags: apt, users, rkhunter

I ran `rkhunter` and found out a warning, that there is a new user called `_apt` on my Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ grep _apt /etc/passwd
_apt:x:124:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

All I found out is, that it seems that this is a kind of sandbox user for "advanced persistent threats". But what exactly is this?

Comment: Interesting question, that user is on my machines as well.

Comment: Same. Ideas: might be related to the new "apt" command in 16.04.

Comment: it is mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771936/permission-error-when-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: That users lacks permissions for locally downloaded packages and thus throws errors

Comment: Please note that APT has two main meanings related to computers... one is the "advanced persistent threats" you mention (which you definitely DON'T want on your PC as they are typically used for remote spying & co), and the other one is "Advanced Packaging Tool", which is the "normal" meaning of "apt" in an Ubuntu/Debian Linux context -- that's the package manager of your system, which owns the _apt users (see the answers for what that user is for).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The user `_apt` is created by the `postinst` script of the `apt` package (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst`):

```
 # add unprivileged user for the apt methods
 adduser --force-badname --system --home /nonexistent  \
     --no-create-home --quiet _apt || true
```

It's the owner of `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` and used by APT to download packages, package list, and other things.

Comment: So basically the same method as seen with apache and other software: you have a dedicated locked down user to do something that pulls something to the machine: user _apt.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04.x, `_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false` is created after `nobody`, `systemd` and `syslog` users under UID ~100+ range. You can always browse users with `less /etc/passwd` (to search use `/` then type `_apt` to find it, `:q` is exit, like vim)