# how to prevent /usr/lib/apt/methods/http from consuming internet quota on startup?

Tags: apt

it is from `apt` package

it isnt directly called as a dbus service:
`egrep "http" /usr/share/dbus-1/services/* -i`

"software & upudates" options are like
- check? NEVER
- security upd? display imediately *1
- other upd? every 2 weeks *2
- new ubu version? NEVER

I think it is *1 and *2 looking for updates, but I want to do that manually and not when I need that little quota (about 8MB) that consumes about 10% of my daily quota!

couldn't find the answer here: [/usr/lib/apt/methods/http eating my bandwidth!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33530/usr-lib-apt-methods-http-eating-my-bandwidth)

obs.: after login, rarely when I wait a few minutes before connecting, it wont be activated and wont consume some of the daily quota

Comment: I suspect that it is related to `unattended-upgrades` - see https://askubuntu.com/a/1006199/66509 .

Comment: @N0rbert thx, I saw no reason to keep unattended-upgrades installed, now I will know on next boot :). I think this could be considered a dup of that question also, not sure tho.